WTSQueryUserToken returning "0x0000000000000000" hImpersonationToken even there is an active session
I am working on window service and trying to execute the .exe file from the code. I looked around the Stack Overflow for help and found this: How to run console application from Windows Service?
The answers suggest, in order to run the exe file, we need to start the process as user because the background services run in isolation (Session 0) where as active session will have different session ID.
The problem I am encountering is, when I try to retrieve "hImpersonationToken" using "WTSQueryUserToken(activeSessionId, ref hImpersonationToken)" it returns "0x0000000000000000" even it has an active session.



// If enumerating did not work, fall back to the old method
if (activeSessionId == INVALID_SESSION_ID)
{
    activeSessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
}

if (WTSQueryUserToken(activeSessionId, ref hImpersonationToken) != 0)
{
    // Convert the impersonation token to a primary token
    bResult = DuplicateTokenEx(hImpersonationToken, 0, IntPtr.Zero,
        (int)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation, (int)TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,
        ref phUserToken);

    CloseHandle(hImpersonationToken);
}

I am using the code from the following repo: https://github.com/murrayju/CreateProcessAsUser/tree/master/ProcessExtensions
Valid session token should be returned if valid active session ID is passed.

What user is the service running as, is it SYSTEM? Why are you trying to do this in the first place? Services really shouldn't be messing with the user session. Run a separate application in the user session (using the normal run-at-login methods) and have that communicate with the service.

@Charlieface is there any alternative of window service and that should run the user session?

I don't know because I don't know what you are trying to achieve. As I said, you can run a separate application in the user session which communicates with the service using IPC (eg Pipes)

@Charlieface I am trying to run another executable file from the window service.

Yes but why? What is this executable supposed to do, and why can't the service do it itself? And why does the excutable need to be in the user session? If it needs to be a GUI or console app to be able to communicate with the user then the service shouldn't be launching it. Instead launch it at logon and use IPC like I keep saying. You're not telling us what you are trying to do, just how you want to achieve it. This is the epitome of an XY Problem.

@Charlieface I am trying to capture screenshots of the active user session from background service at specific intervals. Does it clear or shall I explain more?

So why can't you have a process already running in the user session to do that and pass it to the service? Anyway, what user is the service running under? And please show the definitions for your PInvoke functions.
